# Checkbox item with if condition

Tags: c#, checkbox, listbox

I have a C# application with a check list box with values like A,B,C,D, and another listbox for names (AJay, Arun, Aman, Babu, Balkrishna, Bhomik, Chetan, charu, chinu. Durga, Damini, Dolly).

If I click on A in the list check box, then my listbox should show "Ayay,Arun,Aman", and if I uncheck listbox A, then the listbox should be cleared.

If I check B, then the listbox shall display all names which start with a "B".

If A click A and B, then the listbox should show names starting with "A" and "B".

Please help me solve this.

I have tried if condition but problem is that when I uncheck A check list box it is showing all name start from A but if I check on A and  B then it is not showing and when I uncheck it is not removing value from the list box

Comment: VB.NET or C# ? You mention **both** in your question, but have only tagged C# - so which is it really?? Can't be both at the same time....

Comment: i am using C# for coding.

Comment: "I have tried if condition " - can you show the code?

Comment: Add the names to a `List<string>` that you can then use as the `ListBox.DataSource`. You can use LINQ to filter the strings that `.StartWith([Some char])`. It's a good thing if you specify the platform, e.g., WinForms, Office (VSTO) etc